# How can I handle unfound ELPA packages?

Tags: package, package-repositories

Sometimes I encounter packages claiming to be on [ELPA](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA), yet neither `package-install` nor [1] or [2] list them.

How do I know if the problem is on my or the contributor's side?

Simply manually installing a package wouldn't satisfy my curiosity.

Example:
https://github.com/theanalyst/ix.el

[1] https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/

[2] https://melpa.org/#/ix.el

Comment: you could try https://melpa.org/#/ix

Comment: What happens if you do `M-x package-refresh-contents`? Can you then find the package(s) you are looking for? FWIW, I can install `ix` with no problems.

Comment: Sanity check: Do you *already* have that package installed?  If so, `package-install` won't offer it as an option.

Comment: More things you should check:  #1:  what version of Emacs are you using (version 26.1 and 26.2 have a bug related to package download and you need special code)  #2: does your `package-archive` list include  the URL for MELPA and/or MELPA Stable ?  (the ix is available on both)     #3 `M-x list-packages` will list available *and* installed packages (at the bottom of the long list).  It also displays the archive in a separate column.  If you only see gnu and don't see melpa then you need to add MELPA URL to the `package-archive` list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the MELPA [search interface](https://melpa.org/) or `M-x list-packages` to search from within Emacs.

If you are searching the package collection in Emacs, ensure you have updated with `M-x package-refresh-contents` and have the relevant package sources listed.